# GeckoFX - Get GetHtmlElementById

Tags: c#, dom, geckofx

I've Been struggling with this for over 5 hours now

Example:

```
 <div id='xx'>content</div>
```

How can i access Content of that div via GetHtmlElementById or any other solution based on "Id"

i tried

```
GeckoElement el = browser.Document.GetElementById("xx");
MessageBox.Show(el.TextContent);
```

and im getting NullRefferenceException (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Other example :Navigating to  google.co.uk

```
browser.DocumentCompleted += delegate { 
                MessageBox.Show(browser.DomDocument.GetElementById("gbqfsa").TextContent);

            };
```

MessageBox should show me "Google Search" but no luck

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
>   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Source=gecko fx   StackTrace:
>          at gecko_fx.Form1.b__2(Object , EventArgs ) in C:\Users\drs\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\gecko fx\Form1.cs:line
>   44
>          at Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser.OnDocumentCompleted(EventArgs e) in C:\Users\hindlet\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\geckofx-15.0\Geckofx-Winforms\GeckoWebBrowser.Events.cs:line
>   177
>          at Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser.Gecko.nsIWebProgressListener.OnStateChange(nsIWebProgress
>   aWebProgress, nsIRequest aRequest, UInt32 aStateFlags, Int32 aStatus)
>   in C:\Users\hindlet\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\geckofx-15.0\Geckofx-Winforms\GeckoWebBrowser.cs:line
>   1700   InnerException:

Answer (score 4):

```
            GeckoHtmlElement ele;
            ele = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetHtmlElementById("myData");
            MessageBox.Show(ele.GetAttribute("Value"));
```

This works for me.

Comment: I was searching for this solution for few weeks - thanks a lot.
But maybe You can tell me if this "Value" attribute is "InnerHtml" of ID div ?